# F# reading csv line by line asynchronously with mutable object

Tags: asynchronous, f#, mutable

I've read a lot of posts here that help me a lot with my problem, but all my attempts did not bear fruit.

Hear is my code:

first function (Reading file for use line by line)

```
let readLines filePath = System.IO.File.ReadLines(filePath)
```

Second function (processing the line)
EDIT: typo error I forgot the string line in my first post

```
let processLine (line:string) (myobj:MYOBJ) = 
// ....  some processing
myobj  // I return the object modified
```

Now I would like to process the file asynchronously with this (attempt is not working! but the aim is to explain what I would like it to do)

```
let processAll file =
async { // some processing
        let mutable obj = new MYOBJ()
        readLines file
        |> Seq.iter (fun l -> let obj = proceesLine l ) // I would like to modify the object after each Line
        }
```

I tried using ref and ! to handle the mutation but did not come up with a clean and clear solution.
What would be the best code practice in this case?

POSSIBLE SOLUTION:
thank you for your precious help, here are two possible solutions

1st Solution:

```
let readL (file:string) = 
async {
        let mutable myobj = ref(new MYOBJ())
        use sr = new StreamReader(file)
        while not sr.EndOfStream do
            let line = sr.ReadLine()
            myobj := proccesLine line !myobj
            ()
        sr.Close()
        }
```

2nd solutio: (using CSVReader Library)

```
let readL (file:string) =
async {
        let myobj = new MYOBJ()
        use sr = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(file),false)
        let fcount = sr.FieldCount
        let data : string array = Array.zeroCreate fcount
        let rec readLinloop (readNext, str:CsvReader, obj:MYOBJ) = 
            match readNext with
                | false -> ()
                | true -> sr.CopyCurrentRecordPartTo(data,0)
                          let obj = processLine data obj
                          readL(str.ReadNextRecord(), str, obj)
        readLinLoop(sr.ReadNextRecord(),sr, myobj)
        sr.Dispose()
        }
```

Now, I still wanted to know if it is possible to have an inline function that returns something other than unit type while using Seq.iter. The code would way more easier to read.

EDIT: 3rd solution proposed by iljarn that solved the issue

```
let processAll file =
    async { (MYOBJ(), readLines file) ||> Seq.fold processLine }
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense – you say `processLine` takes a `MYOBJ` but you're actually passing it a `string`, in which case your code is equivalent to `let obj = readLines file |> Seq.last |> processLine`. In any case, by your _description_ of what you want, `ref` is the way to go; show your attempt at using `ref` and it's probably trivially correctable.

Comment: Why do you think this benefits from asynchrony?

Comment: @ildjarn: thx for the comment, I forgot to add the string parameter in the function. Maybe I wasn't clear enough: I have to process the file by reading each line and modify myobj before going to the next Line. Basically, I find that my question is equivalent to ask if it is possible to have an inline function that returns something other than unit after Seq.iter

Comment: @Daniel, I want to use this code asynchronously, that's why I specified in case there is any possible side effects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like an appropriate use-case for [`Seq.fold`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353471.aspx):

```
let processAll file =
    async { (MYOBJ(), readLines file) ||> Seq.fold (fun o l -> processLine l o) }
```

Note that if you reverse the order of `processLine`'s parameters then this could be reduced to:

```
let processAll file =
    async { (MYOBJ(), readLines file) ||> Seq.fold processLine }
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that's exactly what I need, as you may have noticed, I am still an F# newbie, but I was really but I was appealed by the clear and easy syntax of the langage. I'll edit my post to add this, so it can help others to solve the issue with different implementations

Comment: Note that the code in your edit's first solution won't work – `let myobj = proccesLine line myobj` is _shadowing_ the previous `myobj`, not mutating it. You would need `let myobj = ref (MYOBJ())` and `myobj := proccesLine line !myobj`.